# How can I have a fixed div at bottom with margin to show information?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-position

I have a "classic" html5 page that consist of a header, several sections and a footer:

```
<html>

<header>
...
</header>

<section>
...
</section>

<section>
...
</section>

<footer>
...
</footer>

</html>
```

And I need to create a div that will show information -like server responses- for some seconds fixed at the bottom right with some margins like it can be seen in the image below:

For that I created the following HTML + CSS for that container that I've inserted at the bottom of the HTML:

`html`:

```
<div id="divInfoContainer" class="divInfoContainer divInfoContainerNoErrors">
    <div id="divInfoAnimated" class="divInfoAnimated">
        <img src="~/Content/loading.gif" alt="Loading..." />
    </div>
    <div id="divInfoText" class="divInfoText">
    </div>
</div>
```

`css`:

```
.divInfoContainer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 60px;
    right: 30px;
    width: auto;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.divInfoContainerInfo {
    background-color: #2E64FE;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.divInfoContainerErrors {
    background-color: #FF0000;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.divInfoContainerSuccess {
    background-color: #0B610B;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

And it's working quite well, as it can be seen in the attached screenshot, but the problem is that it is not being very responsive, as in a tablet it loses its right margin, as it can be seen in the second attachment.

The fact is not only I'd like to fix the right margin issue, but also create a fully responsive solution with Bootstrap 5 which always creates a fixed div with the same bottom/right margin independently of the screen, but for the moment, and after several attempts, I was not able to achieve that.

What can I try next?

[image: Information div working on a normal screen]

[image: Information div on a tablet]

Comment: Toasts are already implemented in bootstrap: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/toasts/ 
Why you want to re-implement this?

Comment: Well, I don't want to reinvent the wheel @SubCore, it's just I didn't know / remember Bootstrap implements toasts, that's all, but thank you for your input. If you put it as an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Your question may have been received better if you had simplified and showed a demo rather than several detached snippets. You can easily create a Bootstrap-enabled demo using the editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment of writing the question I completely forgot that toasts already exists in Bootstrap, so, as @SubCore suggested I've read the documentation and implemented a toast with no problems at all.